Buen dia, tengo un problema con el envio de correos?
Tengo un problema con el envio de correos desde visual, cuando presiono enviar me sale el error:
Mensaje de error del compilador: CS0246 the type or namespace name 'exception' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error en el codigo fuente:
Línea 72:   try
Línea 73:   {
Línea 74:   client.Send(mailMsg);
Línea 75:   }
Línea 76:   catch (Exception ex)
Línea 77:   {
Línea 78:   // Manejar la excepción adecuadamente (p. ej., registrarla, mostrar un 
mensaje 
Línea 79:    de error, etc.)

Archivo de origen: D:\\WebDGAA\App_Code\Emailer.cs     Línea: 74

Este es el codigo que estoy utilizando, no estoy seguro de a que referencia se refiere el error.
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using webDGAA;
using System.Web;


escribiste exception o Exception?
